Improving the Bound on $\|\Phi^k[\mathbf{I}_d] - \Phi^{k+1}[\mathbf{I}_d]\|$ for a CP Map
I am analyzing a completely positive (CP) linear map $\Phi : \mathbb{R}^{d \times d} \to \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ with the following properties:

$\Phi[\mathbf{I}_d] \preccurlyeq \mathbf{I}_d$,
All eigenvalues of $\Phi$ are in $[0, 1]$,
$\Phi$ maps symmetric matrices to symmetric matrices.

I aim to bound $\|\Phi^k[\mathbf{I}_d] - \Phi^{k+1}[\mathbf{I}_d]\|$ (spectral norm).
Using the spectral mapping theorem, I deduce that the eigenvalues of $\Phi^k - \Phi^{k+1}$ are bounded by $[0, \frac{1}{ek}]$. This leads to:
$$
\|\Phi^k[\mathbf{I}_d] - \Phi^{k+1}[\mathbf{I}_d]\| 
\leq \|\Phi^k[\mathbf{I}_d] - \Phi^{k+1}[\mathbf{I}_d]\|_F 
\leq \|\Phi^k - \Phi^{k+1}\| \cdot \|\mathbf{I}_d\|_F 
\leq \frac{\sqrt{d}}{ek}.
$$
However, I suspect this bound is not tight. Numerically, I have not observed $\|\Phi^k[\mathbf{I}_d] - \Phi^{k+1}[\mathbf{I}_d]\|$ exceeding $\frac{2}{ek}$, independent of $d$.
My Questions:

Can this bound be improved?
Is the dependence on $d$ necessary, or is the actual bound independent of $d$?

Edit:
More information about the bound I already have:
The eigenvalues of $\Phi^k - \Phi^{k+1}$ are of the form $\lambda^k - \lambda^{k+1}$ where $\lambda \in [0, 1]$. To analyze this further, define the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x^k - x^{k+1}$. The maximum of $f(x)$ on $[0, 1]$ occurs at $x = \frac{k}{k+1}$, which gives:
$$
f(x) \leq \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{k+1}\left(1 - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)^k \leq \frac{1}{ek}.
$$
Thus, the eigenvalues of $\Phi^k - \Phi^{k+1}$ are bounded by $\frac{1}{ek}$, supporting the previous analysis.

How does your upper bound $\frac1{ek}$ come about exactly? Assuming $\Phi$ is diagonalizable, spectral mapping yields $|\Phi^k-\Phi^{k+1}|_{2\to 2}=\max_j|\lambda_j|^k|1-\lambda_j|$ which doesn't look like your bound. Or is $e$ for you the spectral radius of $\Phi$ (i.e., $\max_j|\lambda_j|$) and you meant to write $e^k$ instead of $ek$? Either way, you may want to specifiy these details in your original question by using the "Edit" button.

To add to the above question, are you thinking about an explicit family of maps or are you asking for any map that satisfies the properties listed?

@FrederikvomEnde I have edited the question to include those details.

@Rammus I am asking for any map that satisfies the properties listed.

Is this in the Schrödinger or Heisenberg picture?

@NorbertSchuch $\Phi$ is fixed if this is what you are asking.

No, I want to know whether it acts on states or on operators.

@NorbertSchuch It acts on $\mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ symmetric matrices. Does this answer your question?

No. Why do you want to let it act on the identity? Usually a channel acts on density matrices, which have trace 1.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Did you check the lecture notes of Michael Wolf?

@NorbertSchuch Yes.

Note that property 3 is redundant.
